I can't find component “S” in Pspice
I'm reading Learning Pspice document in Pspice(Orcad 22.1), when I reading the part Brushless DC Motor Model circuitof  Pspice Application NotesI find that the component pointed to by the green arrow，but I can't find it in ABM libraryof Pspice,Is there anyone could tell me what it is and why I can't find it in ABM libraryI would very appreciate.
component what I want to know
Learning Pspicepathpath picture 1
 Learning Pspice path picture 2
